# zend showing blank page

Tags: zend-framework

At first I was just having problem in showing my forms then I edited the set_include_path in index.php of my project, but it did not help so I removed the path of forms from the set_include_path and resumed my old code but now it is jus showing a blanck page on each module. Here is my Bootstarp

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
public $frontController= null;
public $root='';
public $layout=null;
public $config = null;

     public function run(){
         $this->setUpEnvironment();
         $this->prepare();
         $response = $this->frontController->dispatch();
        $this->sendResponse($response);
     }

     public function setUpEnvironment(){
       error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
           ini_set('display_errors', true);
           date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
           $this->root = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
       echo $this->root."hello";
     }


     public function setUpConfiguration(){
      $this->config = new Zend_Config_Ini($this->root.'/application/configs/application.ini');     
     }
     public function prepare(){
        $this->setupEnvironment();
        //Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
            require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $this->setupRegistry();
        $this->setupConfiguration();
        $this->setupFrontController();
        $this->startSession();
        $this->setupView('default');//current theme direcotry
        //$this->setupLanguage();

     }
     public function setupFrontController(){
        Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Controller_Front');
        $this->frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $this->frontController->throwExceptions(true);
        $this->frontController->returnResponse(true);
        $this->frontController ->setParam('noErrorHandler', true);
        //echo $this->root;
        $this->frontController->setControllerDirectory(array(
        'default' => $this->root .'/application/default/controllers/',
        'admin' => $this->root .'/application/admin/controllers/',
        //'vendor' => $this->root .'/application/vendor/controllers/',
        ));

     }

  public function setupView($crt_theme)
    {
        $view = new Zend_View;
        $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
        $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer($view);
        Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);
        $view->setScriptPath($this->root .'/application/default/views/scripts/'.$crt_theme);
        $view->setHelperPath($this->root .'/application/default/views/helpers');
        $this->layout = Zend_Layout::startMvc(
        array(
                'layoutPath' => $this->root . '/application/layouts',
                'layout' => 'layout'
                )
                );

        $this->registry->set("theme", $crt_theme);
    }

  public function setupRegistry()
    {
        $this->registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
        $this->registry->set('config', $this->config);
        $this->registry->set('frontController',$this->frontController);
    }

    public function startSession(){
            Zend_Session::start();
    }

    public function sendResponse(Zend_Controller_Response_Http $response)
    {
        $response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', true);
        $response->sendResponse();


    }


}
```

I've made two modules admin and default and made a  form in application/forms/Admin/LoginForm.php

```
<?php
class Application_Form_Admin_LoginForm extends Zend_Form{
public function init(){
  $this->setMethod('post')
       ->setAction('/admin/index');

        $this->addElement(
            'text', 'username', array(
                'label' => 'Username:',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            ));

        $this->addElement('password', 'password', array(
            'label' => 'Password:',
            'required' => true,
            ));

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Login',
            ));
    }


}
```

Here's my IndexController in admin module

```
<?php

class Admin_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
  //  echo "Hello";
        $this->layout = Zend_Layout::startMvc(
          array(
                'layoutPath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts',
                'layout' => 'layout'
                )
                );
                //var_dump($this->layout);
                //$this->view->('header.phtml');
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
    $form = new Application_Form_Admin_LoginForm();
    /*$form->setMethod('post');

        $form->addElement(
            'text', 'username', array(
                'label' => 'Username:',
                'required' => true,
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            ));

        $form->addElement('password', 'password', array(
            'label' => 'Password:',
            'required' => true,
            ));

        $form->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore'   => true,
            'label'    => 'Login',
            ));
      */

    $this->view->login = $form; 
  // $this->view->show =  "I'm in admin index controller";
  /*if((!isset($this->_request->getParam('username')))&&(!isset($this->_request->getParam('password'))))
    {

    }
    else{
    $username = $this->_request()->getPost('username');
    echo $username;
    }    
     */   
    }


}
```

and here is my index.phtml in index folder of application/admin/views/scripts/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<style>
body{
background-color:grey;
}
#login{
background-color:#FFF;
width:350px;
height:200px;
border:1px solid black;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
}
</style>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
         <center>
                <h1>Please Login</h1>
                    <div id="login">   
                    <?php
                echo $this->login;
                //echo $this->show;


                ?>
          </center>
          </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The blank page probably indicates a PHP fatal error but `display_errors` is turned off in `php.ini`.  Check your server `error_log` or enable error reporting in PHP and then try the page again.

Comment: Did the above help you fix it? If not, can you put your application.ini in the question? Also, does each module have its own bootstrap.php?